# base64 encryption - PHP and ASP

Tags: php, asp.net, encryption

Is it possible to encrypt data in ASP and decrypt it in PHP?  I will be writing an application in PHP that will take data from an SQL server database that has been encrypted by another application in ASP.  We therefore need to use the same encryption/decryption method.  Is this possible?

Comment: You do know that base64 is not an encryption method, but an encoding method, right?

Comment: A simple edit changing "crypt" to "code" would make this a somewhat useful question and possibly halt the down-voting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, base64 is not encryption, but encoding. It can be a great way to encode binary objects for transport and storage.

The answer is, yes, if you use base64 encoding in ASP and store the value in the DB, you will be able to use base64_decode in PHP and get the original data back out.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible to encrypt data in ASP and decrypt it in PHP?

Of course.

> We therefore need to use the same encrypt / decrypt method. Is this possible?

Yes

> base64 encryption

base64 is an encoding scheme, it isn't encryption. PHP has [base64 functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php).